# If $a,b$ and $b,c$ are algebraic, can we effectively say $a,c$ are algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, real-numbers

Lets say for two transcendental complex numbers x,y in $\Bbb C$ that they are algebraically independent, if there doesn't exists a non-zero polynomial $p(X,Y) \in \Bbb Q[X,Y]$, such that:

$$p(x,y)=0$$

Now if $a,b$ are algebraically dependent and $b,c$ are algebraically dependent, and the two witness polynomial $p_1(X,Y) \in \Bbb Q[X,Y]$ and $p_2(Y,Z) \in \Bbb Q[Y,Z]$ are given, can we then say, that we can

effecitively find a polynomial $p_3(X,Z) \in \Bbb Q[X,Z]$ that would be witness that $a,c$ are algebraically dependent? So that this relation among transcendental complex numbers is transitive?

BTW: Here is an example:

$$p_1(X,Y) = X (1+Y^2)-2 Y = 0$$

$$p_2(Y,Z) = Z (1+Y^2)-1+Y^2 = 0$$

If $p_1(a,b)=0$ and $p_2(b,c)=0$ then $p_3(a,c)$ where:

$$p_3(X,Z) = X^2+Z^2-1 = 0$$

Comment: Not sure I follow the definition you are using.  Let's let $x=\sqrt 2, y=\pi,p(X,Y)=X^2-2$.  then $p(x,y)=0$ but....

Comment: Yes that is correct, $Q(\sqrt 2,π)$ has transcendental degree 1 and not 2.

Comment: Ok:  with your definition (and my $p(x,y)$) we instantly get that $\sqrt 2$ is algebraically dependent on both $e$ and $\pi$, but $e,\pi$ are independent of each other.

Comment: So $(e,\sqrt2)$ is algebraic and $(\sqrt2,\pi)$ is algebraic? But we don't have $(e,\pi)$ is algebraic. (I mean, technically that's an open problem, but you can replace $e$ with a different real if so)

Comment: The question can be rescued:  "Let's say for two transcendental complex numbers $x,y\in \Bbb C$ that they are algebraically dependent if there exists a non-zero polynomial with rational coefficients such that $p(x,y)=0$. Is such dependence, among transcendental numbers, transitive? I would think the answer is yes, but don't see a proof.

Comment: Yes I am more interested in the transcendental case.

Comment: @MarkFischler  Yes...that looks like a reasonable question.  Feels to me that the answer is no, though.  Something like $e,\pi$ and $\sqrt e, \pi$.

Comment: @lulu Quite.  that says that the converse does not hold (algebraic independence is not transitive). But it does not disproved anything about algebraic dependence, since there is no "witness polynomial" for $e,\pi$ in the first place.

Comment: Algebraic dependence of a set (e.g. $B = \{ a, b \}$) is usually defined for all subsets $B \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ (or any field $K$ over a subset $A$ in general), not only for sets of transcendental numbers. I'd suggest moving the transcendence of $a$ and $b$ from the definition to the problem formulation.

Comment: @MarkFischler  Yes...I was thinking about the transitivity of independence (which, as you say, was not the question).  Inclined to agree about dependence...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P(a,b) = 0$ and $Q(b, c) = 0$, then $R(a,c) = 0$ where $R$ is the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $P(x,y)$ and $Q(y,z)$ with respect to $y$.

In the example given, the resultant of $p_1(x,y) = x (y^2 + 1) - 2 y$ and $p_2(y,z) = z (1+y^2) - 1 + y^2$ with respect to $y$ is $4 x^2 + 4 z^2 - 4$.

Comment: Ok, I need to look further into resultants. Probably the side condition $b$ transcendental is needed, so as to avoid some degenerate $P(x,y)$ and $Q(y,z)$, since we might otherwise get $R(x,z)=0$, i.e. the zero polynomial itself (which is not allowed as a result)? And therefore sometimes a false positive for algebraic independence of $a,c$. Not yet sure, just freely speculating.

Comment: If the resultant is $0$, it means that there is some $b$ such that $P(x,b)$ and $Q(b,z)$  are identically $0$.  Such $b$ will then be algebraic, and its minimal polynomial will divide both $P(x,y)$ and $Q(y,z)$.  Conversely, if $P(x,y)$ and $Q(y,z)$ have a common factor which is a nonconstant polynomial in $y$, then the resultant is indeed $0$.